# Best way to store values in .Net Compact Framework using C#?

Tags: c#

I have a WinForm application and I have many forms in my application .

These forms have some properties which I want to save when the form is closed and when i again load

the forms, I want to populate form properties.

I know some techniques like XmlSerialization or I can write my own xml files to store values.

But I want expert advice to do this in the best way on Compact framework .

What you all expert think could be the best way to store and retrieve data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about SqlLite or similiar?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the existing serialisation mechanisms rather than rolling your own. If small disk footprint is important, use the binary serializer, if human readability is important use the XML one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use .ini files?  Smaller than .xml since its just text, but less of it.